# How can I eliminate "Out of Memory Exception" from this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I get the exception "Out of Memory" and I have ran out of ideas about how to do it.

I have the following tables :

```
create table CGNS
(
CHANNEL SMALLINT NOT NULL,
PNL_DATE     TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
CHANNEL_NAME VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
PRODUCT_LINE  CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PRODUCT_LINE_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
ACCOUNT CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
ACCOUNT_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
AMOUNT NUMERIC(20, 6) NOT NULL
)

create table CP
(
MARKETPLACE_ID NUMERIC(38, 0) NOT NULL,
CHANNEL     SMALLINT NOT NULL,
SHIP_MONTH  DATE NOT NULL,
GL_PRODUCT_GROUP NUMERIC(4, 0) NOT NULL,
PRODUCT_CATEGORY VARCHAR(100) NULL,
PRODUCT_SUBCATEGORY VARCHAR(100) NULL,
PRIME_PLAN  CHAR(10) NULL,
ITEM_SIZE VARCHAR(10) NULL,
CP_COMPONENT  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
AMOUNT  NUMERIC(20, 6) NOT NULL
)

create table ACCOUNT_MAPPER
(
CGNS_ACCOUNT   CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
CP_COMPONENT   VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

create table CHANNEL_MAPPER
(
CGNS_CHANNEL   SMALLINT NOT NULL,
CP_MARKETPLACE_ID  NUMERIC(38, 0) NOT NULL,
CP_CHANNEL  SMALLINT NOT NULL   
)

Create table PRODUCT_LINE_MAPPER
(
CGNS_PRODUCT_LINE   CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
CP_GL_PRODUCT_GROUP NUMERIC(4, 0) NOT NULL
)
```

I want to use the following query to generate data into table SLICED as below :

```
INSERT INTO SLICED

SELECT      CGNS.CHANNEL,              

            CGNS.PRODUCT_LINE,
            CGNS.ACCOUNT,
            CP.PRODUCT_CATEGORY,
            CP.PRODUCT_SUBCATEGORY,  
            CP.ITEM_SIZE,
            CP.PRIME_PLAN,
            CGNS.PNL_DATE,
            CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 

            CASE 
                WHEN CGNS.ACCOUNT = 'QUANTITY_SHIPPED' THEN NULL
                ELSE ((CP.AMOUNT / CP_COMPONENTS_TOTAL_AMOUNTS.TOTAL_AMT_FOR_CP_COMPONENT) * CGNS.AMOUNT)
                             END,

            CASE 
                WHEN CGNS.ACCOUNT = 'QUANTITY_SHIPPED' THEN ((CP.AMOUNT / CP_COMPONENTS_TOTAL_AMOUNTS.TOTAL_AMT_FOR_CP_COMPONENT) * CGNS.AMOUNT) 
                ELSE NULL
                    END,

            CGNS.CURRENCY_CODE,
            'Method',

            CASE -- DRIVER AMOUNT
                WHEN CGNS.ACCOUNT = 'QUANTITY_SHIPPED' THEN NULL
                ELSE CP.AMOUNT
            END,


            CASE  -- DRIVER QTY TO DO
                WHEN CGNS.ACCOUNT = 'QUANTITY_SHIPPED' THEN CP.AMOUNT
                ELSE NULL
            END,

            CP.CURRENCY_CODE

FROM CGNS

JOIN ChannelMapper
            ON CGNS.CHANNEL = ChannelMapper.CGNS_CHANNEL

JOIN  AccountMapper
            ON AccountMapper.CGNS_ACCOUNT = CGNS.ACCOUNT


JOIN  PLMapper
            ON PLMapper.CGNS_PRODUCT_LINE = CGNS.PRODUCT_LINE

JOIN  CP
            ON (
                            ChannelMapper.CP_MARKETPLACE_ID = CP.MARKETPLACE_ID
                            AND ChannelMapper.CP_CHANNEL = CP.CHANNEL
                            AND AccountMapper.CP_COMPONENT = CP.CP_COMPONENT
                            AND PLMapper.CP_GL_PRODUCT_GROUP = CP.GL_PRODUCT_GROUP

               )

JOIN   (SELECT CP_COMPONENT, SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_AMT_FOR_CP_COMPONENT FROM AUTO_PNL_CP GROUP BY CP_COMPONENT) as CP_COMPONENTS_TOTAL_AMOUNTS
            ON CP_COMPONENTS_TOTAL_AMOUNTS.CP_COMPONENT = CP.CP_COMPONENT
```

HERE is what the Explain Plan (Query Execution Plan) looks like :

[image]

Comment: What indexes do you have? And what does the Explain plan show?

Comment: @HLGEM, I've added the Explain plan file. I only have primary keys as indexes. In all 3 joining tables, all the columns are primary keys. and in other tables, every column except for Amount columns are primary keys.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid out of memory exceptions being thrown instead. I made a mistake when expressing my intentions the first time I wrote the question.

Answer (score 1):

Try running parts of the query separately. That way you'll identify which table(s) takes more time to query and can give you ideas on how to improve it. Perhaps it will give you hints on where an index is needed.

Comment: IMO, I would rather add this as a comment, because this answer is really vague.

Comment: Well, this always works for me. So looks like a solution to me.